# Loading data with Ajax don't let me add JavaScript Events

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

today while working with $.ajax method from the JQuery library and loading data from a page based on PHP i have found a problem while trying to attach some events.

I have a html document like that:

```
<html>
```

```
<script src="/public_html/assets/js/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

```
.container {

  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;

}
```

```
<!-- Here goes the container -->

 <div class='wrapper'></div>
```

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

  $(".container").on("contextmenu", function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    alert("It works.");

  });

  $.post("example.php", function(result) {

    $(".wrapper").html(result);

  });


  }); 

</script>
```

Where at the end of the page there is the Ajax request to that PHP file:

```
echo "<div class='container'>";echo "</div>";
```

When the request end, the container appears but when trying to contectmenu it, it doesn't works. However, if it's done through raw html, it works. Any way of solving this?

Comment: Use `$(function(){})`?

Comment: Seems not to work.

Comment: Do you wrap all code within `$(function(){})`? What is purpose of `$("").html(result);`?

Comment: Now is updated, inside the "" there is body and yes, i've wrap all the code inside the $(document).ready(function() {})

Comment: `body` is not defined. Do you mean `"body"`?

Comment: Yes, like this: $("body")

Comment: `$("body").html(result)` replaces all HTML in `document.body` with `result`

Comment: Just modfied the code, in order to make a wrapper where the container goes. But still not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) if element having `.className` `"container"` is appended to `document` after `document` `DOMContentLoaded` or `window` `load` event

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on("contextmenu", ".container", function(event) {
    // do stuff
  })
})
```